# multiple instances of columns into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize if I'm not phrasing this question correctly, but I'm having trouble getting the desired results from a sql query.

```
select u.id as userid,
    quiz.name as quiz_name,
    [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_question_attempts.questionusageid,
    quiz_attempts.sumgrades as attempt_grade,
    mdl_question_attempts.slot as question_number,
    mdl_question_attempts.questionsummary as question, 
    mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer, 
    mdl_question_attempts.responsesummary 
from    [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_user as u
inner join  [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_quiz_attempts as quiz_attempts on u.id = quiz_attempts.userid
inner join [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_quiz as quiz on quiz.id = quiz_attempts.quiz
left join [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_question_attempts on quiz_attempts.id = [moodle_test].   [dbo].mdl_question_attempts.questionusageid 
where quiz.course = 2a
```

resulting in data like

```
userid  quiz_name   questionusageid attempt_grade   question_number question    rightanswer responsesummary
180 Module 2 Pre-Test   285 6.00000 1   A properly structured team yields all of the following benefits, EXCEPT:: A leader is clearly identified; A clear plan of care; The patient is involved in the care process; Team members know their roles and responsibilities A clear plan of care    The patient is involved in the care process
180 Module 2 Pre-Test   285 6.00000 2   A Contingency Team includes all of the following characteristics, EXCEPT:: It is formed for emergent or specific events; It is time-limited (e.g., Code Team, Disaster Response Team, Rapid Response Team); It is composed of team members drawn from a variety of Core Teams; It performs day-to-day operational management    It performs day-to-day operational management   It performs day-to-day operational management
180 Module 2 Pre-Test   285 6.00000 3   Team members include anyone who can take action in the process of patient care. Which of the following characteristics do team members share?: Roles and responsibilities that change; Individual goals that take priority over the team's mission; Accountability only to the team leader; A need to remain continually informed for effective team functioning    A need to remain continually informed for effective team functioning    A need to remain continually informed for effective team functioning
180 Module 2 Pre-Test   285 6.00000 4   Examples of effective strategies for involving patients in their care include all of the following, EXCEPT:: Reviewing the hospital bill with the patient at discharge; Conducting handoffs at the patient's bedside; Providing patients with tools for communicating with their care team; Including patients in bedside rounding  Reviewing the hospital bill with the patient at discharge   Reviewing the hospital bill with the patient at discharge
```

How can I join the trio of question, system answer, and correct answer so that all a user's question responses are in one row?

Comment: And what is the current output (I presume the results listed above are desired)?

Comment: Are you trying to combine multiple fields in the same column into one field?

Comment: do you need to google "SQL PIVOT"?

Comment: You should be consistent when using aliases. You use them sometimes and not others. Makes for very hard to decipher code. BTW, 4 part naming in a column list is deprecated. In the future you will be forced to use an alias.

Comment: So... I'm still a bit foggy on the goal.  Are you saying that you want to see the four rows shown above compressed into a single row with question numbers 1,2,3 and 4 along with their responses all in that same row?

Comment: Ah.  Or is it that a user can take this quiz many times (quiz attempts) and you want to see every response that user made to 'question 1' on one row, and then every response that user made to 'question 2' on the next row, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  The main problem here is that we can't know how many attempts will be made.  SQL has no easy way to transform a variable number of rows to a variable number of columns.  So, all of these responses are going to have to be concatenated into some kind of delimited string and crammed into a single field.  XPATH queries can provide a way to do this.

Below, the CTE baseTable is the same query you provided above.  Then, the dynamic table Main holds the essential result, but there is a trailing delimiter (using a pipe here "|" -- but you can do whatever) in answerList that we'll need to strip out.  So, this first query on the table 'Main' only is there to slice off that last delimiter

The next query 'outerQuery' identifies the columns that are unique, that are the 'sameness' that you don't want repeated.  It selects these rows distinctly so you get a resultset with only one of each of them.  Basically, your User/Question information

The 'innerQuery' uses XML PATH to squish the responses together along with our pipe delimiter, lining them up according to the distinct rows we identified in the outer query.

I hope that makes sense; here's the code.  Untested.  Almost guaranteed to contain at least one typo. Hope it helps.

```
WITH baseTable as
(
select u.id as userid,
    quiz.name as quiz_name,
    [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_question_attempts.questionusageid,
    quiz_attempts.sumgrades as attempt_grade,
    mdl_question_attempts.slot as question_number,
    mdl_question_attempts.questionsummary as question, 
    mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer, 
    mdl_question_attempts.responsesummary 
from    [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_user as u
inner join  [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_quiz_attempts as quiz_attempts on u.id = quiz_attempts.userid
inner join [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_quiz as quiz on quiz.id = quiz_attempts.quiz
left join [moodle_test].[dbo].mdl_question_attempts on quiz_attempts.id = [moodle_test].   [dbo].mdl_question_attempts.questionusageid 
where quiz.course = 2a
)

Select Main.userid, Main.quiz_name, Main.questionusageid, Main.attemmpt_grade, Main.question_number, Main.question, Main.rightanswer,
       Left(Main.answerList,Len(Main.answerList)-1) As answerList
From
    (
        Select distinct userid, quiz_name, questionusageid, attempt_grade, question_number, question, rightanswer,  
            (
                SELECT innerQuery.responsesummary + '|' AS [text()]
                FROM baseTable innerQuery
                WHERE innerQuery.userid = outerQuery.userid 
                      AND innerQuery.questionusageid = outerQuery.questionusageid
                      AND innerQuery.question_number= outerQuery.question_number
                ORDER BY innerQuery.userid, innerQuery.questionusageid, innerQuery.question_number
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) answerList
        From baseTable outerQuery
    )[Main]
```